# Surface current density of current trough infinitesimally small area

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

The surface current density of a wire with radius $R$ is given by $K  = \frac{I}{2\pi R}$ but what if the bounded area is infinitesimally small, for example when the current only goes through the surface of the wire but not the inside. What would $K$ be then?